# Import CAD Annotation into an existing Geodatabase Annotation Feature Class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, import, annotation, cad

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1, and I need to automate (with Python using arcpy) importing the annotation of many DWG files into the same file geodatabase annotation feature class. I can't use the ImportCADAnnotation tool because it always wants to create a new annotation class, and I don't want to overwrite the annotation feature class each time (or create new ones each time).

I've been attempting to use SearchCursor on the CAD annotation and InsertCursor on an empty GDB annotation feature class, and I can populate values for most of the fields (I've made the annotation shape into a Polygon which the GDB seems to need), but I don't know how to populate the Element field of the GDB annotation (It stores a BLOB field of the symbology and text geometry). Is this possible?

Comment: You can use Import CAD Annotation with multiple sources. Just add all the CAD Annotations from all the the sources and output into a single annotation feature class. Scale will be an issue if multiple drawings are at different scales